# I declared my variable with let but it is still not in global scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a component appear on condition of 'uneligible=(age<18)' so I tried to declare uneligible out of his function's scope and declaring it with let because I know the value will change later

```
    let uneligible;
  const handleSaveGeneral = async (e) => {
    var dateOfBirth = "2007-01-01";
    var split_dob = dateOfBirth.split("-");
    var month = split_dob[1];
    var day = split_dob[2];
    var year = split_dob[0];
    var dob_asdate = new Date(year, month, day);
    var today = new Date();
    var mili_dif = Math.abs(today.getTime() - dob_asdate.getTime());
    var age = mili_dif / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365.25);
    console.log(age);
    uneligible = age < 18;
  };
```

now it's undefined in the syntax around the component and the component doesn't appear

```
<div>
      {uneligible && (
        <Alert variant="filled" severity="error">
          This is an error alert — check it out!
        </Alert>
      )}
    </div>
```

code sandox:https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-wave-qyuc4?file=/src/App.js:602-767

I didn't use stateful variable because of that issue:[conditional rendering is not working in my functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865227/conditional-rendering-is-not-working-in-my-functional-component/65865341#65865341)

Comment: According to the codesandbox you provided, `handleSaveGeneral` is never used, so `uneligible` never gets set.

Comment: Firstly, you never call your function so the value will always be undefined. Secondly, that's not how React works. If you want to update the DOM you have to commit changes to a *stateful* variable, either a reducer or more commonly a `useState` hook. Any values declared in the body of the component are lost (or reset) as soon as the component rerenders because they belong to the previous render.

Comment: Why did you declare `handleSaveGeneral` as `async`?

Comment: you should probably have a look at some more react tutorials as your code is full of syntax errors. in your case, uneligible is a simple variable, not a stateful one. which means your component won't rerender if you change it

Comment: everyone please look at the updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let` allows you to declare variables that are limited to the scope of a block statement or expression on which it is used, unlike the `var` keyword, which declares a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope.

Just like `const` the `let` does not create properties of the window object when declared globally (in the top-most scope).

To achieve what you want you can use `var` / `window.uneligible` instead of `let`

Comment: I changed it to var in the sandbox and still doesn't work

Comment: I added a button to use it

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at react docs to understand how it'e ecosystem revolves around state. Your code should look something like this with the given details - https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-buck-s2qvo

Instead of having a useEffect, you can call the same function when there is a certain event, say a `click` event on a button click.

Regarding your updated question - You were setting state again and again because each render due to setting a state will again call the state updater function and it will go on.... This is not what you want if you wanted a one-time initial render where you have no handler at all.

But now since you are going to handle the alert's visibility via a function handler, its your responsibility to add some sort of state to this component so that inside that handler you update the visibility state and display your Alert.