# I am trying to call a function from useEffect hook and it's giving me undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call function  'handleSaveGeneral' from inside useEffect hook

```
const ProfilePage = (props) => {
  const [uneligible, setUneligible] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleSaveGeneral = (e) => {
      var dateOfBirth = "2007-01-01";
      var split_dob = dateOfBirth.split("-");
      var month = split_dob[1];
      var day = split_dob[2];
      var year = split_dob[0];
      var dob_asdate = new Date(year, month, day);
      var today = new Date();
      var mili_dif = Math.abs(today.getTime() - dob_asdate.getTime());
      var age = mili_dif / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365.25);
      setUneligible(age < 18);
    };
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outline-primary" onClick={handleSaveGeneral}>
        Save
      </Button>
      {uneligible && (
        <Alert variant="filled" severity="error">
          This is an error alert — check it out!
        </Alert>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

the 'save' Button also doesn't render for no reason, I am trying to show Alert when we click 'save' but the function 'handleSaveGeneral' is giving me undefined in the code sandbox of the problem

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-field-xqf91?file=/src/App.js:257-274

Comment: `handleSaveGeneral` in different scope for some reason... what are you trying to do with `useEffect`?

Comment: I am trying to prevent state from re-rendering state infinitely check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65875644/i-declared-my-variable-with-let-but-it-is-still-not-in-global-scope/65875748#65875748

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const` declaration is bloc-scope

So you should define the `handleSaveGeneral` function outside of `useEffect` and call it inside, so that other components can get access to it

## update:

Make sure you add an array to useEffect's dependency to avoid infinite loop

```
    const handleSaveGeneral = (e) => {
      var dateOfBirth = "2007-01-01";
      var split_dob = dateOfBirth.split("-");
      var month = split_dob[1];
      var day = split_dob[2];
      var year = split_dob[0];
      var dob_asdate = new Date(year, month, day);
      var today = new Date();
      var mili_dif = Math.abs(today.getTime() - dob_asdate.getTime());
      var age = mili_dif / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365.25);
      setUneligible(age < 18);
    };
  useEffect(() => {
handleSaveGeneral()
  },[]);
```

here is the whole code

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Alert from "@material-ui/lab/Alert";

const ProfilePage = (props) => {
  const [uneligible, setUneligible] = React.useState(false);
  const handleSaveGeneral = (e) => {
    var dateOfBirth = "2007-01-01";
    var split_dob = dateOfBirth.split("-");
    var month = split_dob[1];
    var day = split_dob[2];
    var year = split_dob[0];
    var dob_asdate = new Date(year, month, day);
    var today = new Date();
    var mili_dif = Math.abs(today.getTime() - dob_asdate.getTime());
    var age = mili_dif / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365.25);
    setUneligible(age < 18);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    handleSaveGeneral()
  },[]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outline-primary" onClick={handleSaveGeneral}>
        Save
      </Button>
      {uneligible && (
        <Alert variant="filled" severity="error">
          This is an error alert — check it out!
        </Alert>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProfilePage;
```

Comment: This will result in an infinite loop. OP should add a dependency array to the `useEffect`.